# R data.table - add row based on value

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I have data.table x below

```
x <- data.table(id=c('A1', 'B1'), start=c(1,1), stop=c(4,5))
```

| id | start | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 4 |
| B1 | 1 | 5 |

I would like to expand row. Is it possible to use rbindlist using Map to generate data.table as below?

| id | start | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 2 |
| A1 | 2 | 3 |
| A1 | 3 | 4 |
| B1 | 1 | 2 |
| B1 | 2 | 3 |
| B1 | 3 | 4 |
| B1 | 4 | 5 |

Comment: If you aren't locked in to using `data.table`, you can use `tidyr::expand` for this job https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence from `start` to `stop` for each `id`. Use `shift` to get next value and drop the `NA` rows.

```
library(data.table)
x <- x[, .(start = seq(start, stop)), id]
x[, stop := shift(start, type = 'lead'), id]
x[!is.na(stop)]

#   id start stop
#1: A1     1    2
#2: A1     2    3
#3: A1     3    4
#4: B1     1    2
#5: B1     2    3
#6: B1     3    4
#7: B1     4    5
```

Here's an equivalent `tidyverse` way -

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  mutate(start = map2(start, stop, seq)) %>%
  unnest(start) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(stop = lead(start)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(!is.na(stop))
```

Comment: Just trying to understand....You used .() in 2nd like "x <- x[, .(start = seq(start, stop)), id]" and use ':=' for 3rd line "x[, stop := shift(start, type = 'lead'), id]".  Is that because reference operator wont work with seq() because it returns more than one value?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `:=` is used when your output is same as number of rows in the data. Since in the first case we return more than one value for each row I used `.(`.